# Swift mapview layer mask crops/moves the view. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: ios, swift, applet, mapkit, gradient

I want to add a fadeview on 50% of the mapview below. But as soon as I add the CAGradientLayer to the mapview.layer.mask I get the weird result that looks like it crops the mapview, or moves it down and to the left?

When I run the debug view hierarchy I get the correct result it seems (image 1), but on the device it looks totally different (image 2).

```
override func viewDidLoad() {    

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    // Gradient
    let gradientMaskLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientMaskLayer.frame = mapView.bounds
    gradientMaskLayer.colors = [UIColor.clear.cgColor, UIColor.black.cgColor]
    gradientMaskLayer.locations = [0.0, 0.05]

    mapView.layer.mask = gradientMaskLayer
    mapView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
}
```

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxVWG.png)
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysM45.png)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!

I used the main views max bounds instead of the mapviews.

So I replaced

```
gradientMaskLayer.frame = mapView.bounds
```

with:

```
gradientMaskLater.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: view.bounds.maxX, height: view.bonds.maxY)
```

Cheers!